# How to store the output and print it back again with breaking output into new lines

Tags: shell-script

I want to store the output in a variable and want to be displayed as follows.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1

printf "file size: %s\n" \ 
               du "$dir" -hab | sort -n -r |tail -n 2
```

I want to store this output in a variable and print it back as desired output.

My desired output:

```
$ ./filestats test
 minimum file size: 15 
    test/subdir/file3.txt
    test/file5.txt
```

Comment: What exactly are you after? It looks like you want i) the size of the smallest file and ii) the list of file names. Is that correct? And what about sub-directories? Should they be considered as files? Should they be read recursively?

Comment: Please note: `-h` option of `du` and `-n` option of `sort` will never do what you expect (i.e. sort numeric values, because `1.2M` isn't numeric.)

Comment: @terdon Im looking for the smallest file size along with its directory path, where the file is residing in a directories or subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1

minfile=$( du "$dir" -hab | sort -n -r | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }' )
out=$( du "$dir" -hab | sort -n -r | tail -n 2 | awk '{ print $2 }' )

printf "Minimum file size: %s\n" "$minfile"  
printf "$out\n"
```

Example output of the above code:

```
Minimum file size: 94
/home/krt/my-scripts/multissh.sh
/home/krt/my-scripts/vpn.sh
```

Comment: Instead of using `tail` command Is there any command to show small file sizes automatically when we execute shell script.

Comment: I need one tab space for the ouput path directory. Where I have to insert `\t`. could you please let me know

Comment: This will i) only find the two smallest, not all and ii) break on file names containing spaces.

Comment: @krt  your code works perfectly but i need a tabspace for the directories path. could you please let me know.

Comment: @buddhasreekanth Good to here it works. You can change this `printf "$out\n"` to `printf "$out" | awk '{ print "\t",$1 }'` which will insert tabs before the paths.

Comment: @Krt perfectly working. Instead of using `tail -n 1 or tail -n 2 and so on` command, Is there any command to show small files sizes along with their directory path. for example, a directory has 20 files and 10 files are smallest file sizes with equal size( say file1-10kb....file10-kb). To display that How to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
size=$(du -hab "$dir" | sort -n -r | tail -n 2)
printf "File size: %s" "$size"
```

Comment: I am getting an error like this: `minimum file size: 15 testdir/subdir3/subdir4/file3.txt
15 testdir/subdir1/file5.txt
` Instead of showing number 15 once it displays twice. How to get rid of that?

Comment: This fails on file names with spaces and will only find the two smallest files, not all. You also want a trailing newline for the `printf` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a script that will find i) the smallest file size in a directory and its subdirectories and ii) list all files that are of that smallest size. If so, you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
du -ab "$@" |
    awk -F"\t" '($1<=s || NR==1){
                  s=$1; 
                  a[s]=a[s]"\n\t"$2; 
                  a[-1]=1
                }
                END{
                 if(a[-1]){
                  printf "Smallest file size:%d%s\n",s,a[s]}
                 }'
```

Or, just run it as a one-liner:

```
du -ab | awk -F"\t" '($1<=s || NR==1){s=$1;a[s]=a[s]"\n\t"$2;a[-1]=1}END{if(a[-1]){printf "Smallest file size:%d%s\n",s,a[s]}}'
```

**Sample output:**

```
$ a.sh .
Smallest file size:42
    ./foo/file2
    ./file13
    ./file with spaces
```

#### Explanation

- `du -ab` : There's no point in using both `-b` and `-h`, they override each other. This will print the sizes of all files and directories.
- `awk -F"\t"` : run `awk`, setting the input field separator to a tab. That way, file names with spaces will be treated correctly.
- `($1<=s || NR==1){...}` : if this file's size is less than the smallest size or if this is the first file found.

  - `a[s]=a[s]"\n"$2;` : the associative array `a` has each file size as a key and the list of files (separated by newlines) as the value. If this file is smaller than or as small as the smallest, add it to the array.
  - `s=$1;` : set `s` to the new smallest size;
  - `a[-1]=1` : this is just used so that the script prints no output if no files were found. We set it to `1` if at least one file has been found.
- `END{}` : this gets executed after all of the input has been read. At this point, `s` will be the smallest file size found.

  - `if(a[-1]){...}` : if at least one file or directory has been found;
  - `printf "Minimum file size:%d%s\n",s,a[s]` : print it/them.

#### Notes

- This can deal with file names that contain spaces (it breaks if they contain tabs or newlines);
- It can deal with multiple target directories;
- It returns no output if no files/directories were found;
- Lists *all* the files of the smallest size, not only the last N (as you get if you use `tail`).